# Liferay-7 with MySQL-8 database not working

Tags: mysql, liferay-7

When trying to install Liferay-7 with MySQL-8 database, the command prompt is getting stuck on below error and installation is not getting completed

```
2018-07-06 12:41:15.163 INFO  [main][ReleaseLocalServiceImpl:130] Create tables and populate with default data
2018-07-06 12:41:40.559 WARN  [main][BaseDB:484] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'system tinyint,_        maxUsers integer,_      active_ tinyint_) engine InnoDB' at line 10: create table Company (_    mvccVersion bigint default 0 not null,_ companyId bigint not null primary key,_ accountId bigint,_      webId varchar(75) null,_        key_ longtext null,_    mx varchar(200) null,_  homeURL longtext null,_ logoId bigint,_ system tinyint,_        maxUsers integer,_      active_ tinyint_) engine InnoDB;_ [Sanitized]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL 8.0 has been [released in April 2018](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/), Liferay 7.0 has been [released in April 2016](https://community.liferay.com/en_GB/blogs/-/blogs/liferay-portal-7-0-ce-release). It's a good guess that Liferay hasn't been tested on a database that wasn't out for two more years after its initial release.

You can find the [compatibility matrix for the enterprise version here](https://web.liferay.com/en/services/support/compatibility-matrix). It's typically a good indicator for supported infrastructure of the CE release as well (with the difference of being limited to open source databases and appservers). This document lists MySQL 5.6, 5.7 and MariaDB 10 as supported databases for Liferay DXP 7.0, which is the enterprise supported version parallel to Liferay Portal 7.0 CE.

Comment: It means Liferay DXP 7.x does not support MySQL v8. So, we should avoid it. I am using latest MariaDB-10.3.8 with Liferay DXP-7.1.0-ga1 and it's working fine. Thanks for your all details @Olaf Kock.

Answer (score 2):

As [MySQL documentation on reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-S) in MySQL v8 says:

> SYSTEM (R) added in 8.0.3 (reserved)

So, the word `system` is reserved and therefore you need to enclose it by backticks:

```
... `system` tinyint ...
```